# ngFor em array dentro de outro array com links da API

Tags: angular, angular-7

Eu estou usando a API publica swapi para listar filmes do star wars em uma lista e dentro de cada filme quero listar os personagens, a resposta em json da api é essa:

```
{
"title": "A New Hope",
"episode_id": 4,
"opening_crawl": "It is a period of civil war.\r\nRebel spaceships, striking\r\nfrom a hidden base, have won\r\ntheir first victory against\r\nthe evil Galactic Empire.\r\n\r\nDuring the battle, Rebel\r\nspies managed to steal secret\r\nplans to the Empire's\r\nultimate weapon, the DEATH\r\nSTAR, an armored space\r\nstation with enough power\r\nto destroy an entire planet.\r\n\r\nPursued by the Empire's\r\nsinister agents, Princess\r\nLeia races home aboard her\r\nstarship, custodian of the\r\nstolen plans that can save her\r\npeople and restore\r\nfreedom to the galaxy....",
"director": "George Lucas",
"producer": "Gary Kurtz, Rick McCallum",
"release_date": "1977-05-25",
"characters": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/2/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/3/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/4/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/5/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/6/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/7/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/8/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/9/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/10/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/12/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/13/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/14/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/15/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/16/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/18/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/19/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/81/"
],
"planets": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/planets/3/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/"
],
"starships": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/2/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/3/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/5/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/9/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/10/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/11/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/12/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/13/"
],
"vehicles": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/4/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/6/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/7/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/8/"
],
"species": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/species/5/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/species/3/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/species/2/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/species/1/",
    "https://swapi.co/api/species/4/"
],
"created": "2014-12-10T14:23:31.880000Z",
"edited": "2015-04-11T09:46:52.774897Z",
"url": "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/"
```

}

O array com os personagens da links para /people que é onde ficam os personagens na api, o ngFor que eu fiz é esse:

```
  <li *ngFor="let filme of filmes$">
      <p>{{ filme.title }} , {{filme.episode_id}}</p>
      <p>{{ filme.opening_crawl }}</p>
      <p *ngFor= "let character of filme.characters">{{character}}</p>
  </li>
```

mas ele lista os links, queria saber como é possível eu listar os personagens nesse caso, o código para buscar os filmes é:

```
   getFilmes(): Observable<Filme[]> {
      return this.http.get<Filme[]>(`${this.url}/films`)
        .pipe(
          map((resposta: any) => resposta.json())
        )
  }
```

Comment: https://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer usando ForkJoin:

```
 getFilmesById(id: number): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/films/${id}`)
  .pipe(switchMap(movie => new Observable(observer => {
    forkJoin(movie.characters.map((character: string) => this.http.get(character)))
      .subscribe((characters: any) => {
        movie.characters = characters;
        observer.next(movie);
        observer.complete();
      });
    forkJoin(movie.starships.map((starship: string) => this.http.get(starship)))
      .subscribe((starships: any) => {
        movie.starships = starships;
        observer.next(movie);
        observer.complete();
      });
    forkJoin(movie.planets.map((planet: string) => this.http.get(planet)))
      .subscribe((planets: any) => {
        movie.planets = planets;
        observer.next(movie);
        observer.complete();
      });
  })));
```